# GpsStatusListener: no satellites used in fix although status is GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX

Tags: android, gps

I added a gps status listener to my location manager in order see when I get the first fix.

When I receive the GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX I then loop through all the satellites, but why is none of them used in the fix? (`usedInFix()`).

My log says 'false' for all satellites?

```
final class GpsStatusListener implements GpsStatus.Listener {
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int i) {

        if (i==GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX) {
            Log.d(APP, "gpsx.fixed.");
            for (GpsSatellite sat:locationManager.getGpsStatus(null).getSatellites()) {
                Log.d(APP, "gpsx.GpsStatus.Sat.fixed: " + sat.usedInFix());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Log:

```
gpsx.fixed.
gpsx.GpsStatus.Sat.fixed: false
gpsx.GpsStatus.Sat.fixed: false
gpsx.GpsStatus.Sat.fixed: false
```

Comment: seems to me like a bug or at least some 'unlogic', reported it at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10134

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588982/retrieving-of-satellites-used-in-gps-fix-from-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to me like a bug or at least some 'unlogic', reported it at

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10134